# How would surface dipoles change the internal potential in a conducting sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, semiconductor-physics, conductors, nanoscience

In the nanoscience literature, there is a model of semiconductor nanoparticle doping which ascribes the effect to surface dipoles shifting the absolute state energies relative to the environmental Fermi level. The original reference [Jeong et al., J. Phys. Chem. Lett. 2014](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jz500436x) attributes reversible n or p-doping of HgS quantum dots to surface dipoles formed by exposure to either negative sulfur or positive mercury ions. The relevant excerpt:

> As shown in Figure 3B, a surface dipole pointing inward
> (positive end on the surface) raises the electric potential inside
> (+ V) which stabilizes the electron (− eV) and increases the
> work function. For a sphere with a radius much larger than the
> dipole layer thickness, the energy shift is $\Delta E = \sigma d/\varepsilon\varepsilon_0$ (eV) where σd is the surface dipole density with the positive direction toward outside and ε is the dielectric constant in the dipole
> layer. The eﬀect can potentially be large. Assuming that the surface dipole
> due to the ions alternates between +1 D and −1 D pointing
> outside the particle, and that each ion occupies a surface of 20
> $Å^2$, as an estimated surface coverage of ions on the (111) plane,
> using the smallest screening with ε = 1, the energy shift is ∼ ±
> 1.8 eV.

The accompanying cartoon/figure:

> [image]

- **Can someone offer a derivation and/or more in-depth electrostatic explanation for the state energy shift $\Delta E$?** My guess is that if (and only if?) the surface dipole coverage is non-uniform, a potential forms across the particle which acts similarly to the Stark effect. My electrostatics is rusty, however, and I'm not sure if this is even a correct analogy here.
- It seems like this effect is related to band bending in bulk semiconductors, but my understanding is that is usually explained as a more chemical donor/acceptor effect. Is there in fact a connection?

Thanks everyone!